# Ruby/Rails: Decode HTML after #inspect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array:

```
arr = ["foo", "bar"]
```

To use this data in some Javascript, I need to use `inspect` like so:

```
series: [
  {
    data: <%= arr.inspect %>
  }
]
```

Unfortunately, this produces:

```
[&quot;foo&quot;, &quot;bar&quot;]
```

which can't be read by the Javascript.  I have tried decoding using `HTMLEntities.new.decode` and `CGI.unescapeHTML`, but still get the encoded double quotes.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is within a Rails app using ERB.

Comment: Are you using ERB to process this template or are you using a framework?

Comment: Did you try using the escape_javascript helper ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to use `inspect` for that, `inspect` is for producing human readable output for debugging, logging, and such. If you want to dump your data into JavaScript, use JSON:

```
data: <%=r arr.as_json %>
```

That will give you something like:

```
data: ["foo","bar"]
```

and everything will be properly escaped and encoded for use in JavaScript (hence the `r` for `raw` in the ERB).